# Leer archivo JSON en android

Tags: java, javascript, android-studio, nodejs

Intento hacer un log-in, siendo programado el servidor en Javascript (usando node.js). El problema que tengo (que vi que es muy común pero aún así no le encuentro la vuelta a mi problema) es que cuando intento leerlo me sale el siguiente mensaje: `Value //Objeto JSON// of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`.
El código del servidor es el siguiente:

```
app.post('/Acceso', function(req, res){
    var conDB=DB();
    var UsuarioReg=req.body.Usuario;
    var ContraReg=req.body.Contra;
    conDB.query('SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario = ? and Contra= ?',
        [UsuarioReg,ContraReg],
        function(err,rows){
            conDB.end();
        if(err)
        {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!rows.length)
            {
                var obj='{"log":"no"}';
                return res.json(JSON.stringify(obj));
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(rows);
                var obj='{"log":"si"}';
                return res.json(JSON.stringify(obj));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

El código del usuario que se encarga de leer lo que dice en log es este:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    public class LeerConsulta{

        JSONObject jsonResponse;
        String content="";

        public LeerConsulta(String data)
        {
            content=data;
        }
        protected String onPostExecute()
        {
            try
            {
                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
                String log=(String)jsonResponse.get("log");
                return log;
            }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                String error=e.getMessage();
                return error;
            }
        }

    }
```

Se que puede estar mal tanto como escribo la cadena que se transforma en JSON al enviarla al usuario, como la forma en como tomo su contenido. Por eso es que envío ambos.
EDICION: el codigo del main que se encarga de hacer la relacion con la clase que lee la consulta en JSON es el siguiente:

```
aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String usuario=Usuario.getText().toString();
                String contra=Contra.getText().toString();
                Ajax logIn=new Ajax(new String[]{
                        "Usuario="+usuario,
                        "Contra="+contra
                });
                try {
                    String acceso = logIn.execute(IP_ADDRESS+"Acceso").get();
                    LeerConsulta lec=new LeerConsulta(acceso);
                    String conf=lec.onPostExecute();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, conf, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   /* if(!acceso.equals("si"))
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuario y/o clave no valida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Accedido.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }*/
                } catch(Exception exc){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exc.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te sale dice todo.

> Value //Objeto JSON// of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to
>   JSONObject

Reemplaza en tu Java:

```
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
```

Por:

```
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
String log = (String) jsonResponse.get("log");
System.out.println("log: " + log);
```

Lo que envia tu servidor NodeJS esta bien. En tu Java nomas es el problema.

Comment: no me funciono. Edite el codigo que se muestra en la pregunta como para que se vea como esta ahora. El tema es que yo tengo una clase en la cual recibo un string el cual es el objeto JSON. Luego, creo un objeto proveniente de esta clase y, en el main, pongo que otra variable string es igual al resultado de la funcion que aparece ahi. Justamente, lo que me parece que esta mal es como hago el JSON en NodeJS en parte por una cuestion de respetar comillas o algo al crearlo....Te fijaste que no haya sido eso?

Comment: si tienes alguna duda acerca de como hice el main puedo editar la pregunta y agregar eso que estoy diciendo

Comment: Como no tengo acceso al código completo, no puedo saber con exactitud a las cosas. Pero lo que veo jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content); Tu content no debería de ser this,content. Donde esta la parte que recibe del servidor NodeJS al Java. Ahi le pasas el content como string??

Comment: ahi agregue el código del main. El problema que tengo desde node, al agregar las comillas, es que al estar eso dentro de un string me esta forzando a que sean simples ya que al ser dobles tira error....vi una funcion para resolver eso en otra pregunta en la pagina pero no me acuerdo cual era. voy a ver si puedo solucionarlo con eso

Comment: Hice un cambio en la cadena cuando la crea en el node.JS (se puede observar en la pregunta) y ahora cuando solicito lo que dice el String, me pone en el objeto JSON "{"log\":\"si\"}". No se por que lo hace....hice algun cambio importante?

Comment: LO SOLUCIONE!!! no estaba mal lo que pusiste del codigo de java. El problema era que en el nodeJS estaba haciendo algo mal escribir el JSON y mandar la cadena. Lo que hice directamente fue escribir el JSON y mandar eso en lugar de escribir una cadena y convertirla. Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda

Comment: Que bueno. Si se solucionó el problema, podrías marcar como solucionado. Muchas gracias